# In Android's WebView, what's the different between `DomStorage`, `Database`, `AppCache`?

Tags: javascript, android, caching, local-storage, android-webview

In Android's WebView, what's the difference between `DomStorage`, `Database` and `AppCache`?

I'm confused about these three settings. Now I need a instance of WebView that I can use `localStorage` in JavaScript.

Here is an example:

```
        if (localStorage['avatar_user_' + nick]) {
        obj.src = localStorage['avatar_user_' + nick];
    } else {
        var url = avatar_path + nick + '/avatar.jpg';
        new Oauth().img("jpeg", url,
            function(data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    obj.src = data;
                    localStorage['avatar_user_' + nick] = data;
                }
            }, function() {}
        );
    }
```

In the above code I really get the image from the web, and it will be loaded from the localStorage the next time I need it, but the storage only lasts as long as the app's lifetime.

If I restart  my app, then the image will be loaded from the web again.

I setup my WebView as follows:

```
    mWebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setDatabasePath("file:///data/data/com.xxx/databases");
```

but I can see the files in  `file:///data/data/com.xxx/databases` remain unchanged when I'm adding something into localStorage.

So my question is *how to make my webpages store data and keep them after the app is closed?*

And does it matters if I use multiple WebView in a app and point the `DatabasePath` to the same folder?

And if you can tell me the difference between `DomStorage`, `Database` and `AppCache` it would be so much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not hundert percent sure, but DomStorage seems like an synonym for WebStorage. This is a technique to store data on client site as key=value pairs.
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Database means that the client-side SQL database will be enabled.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

And AppCache is a technique to make whole websites available for offline usage.
http://appcachefacts.info/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! I just made a mistake that I use `file:///data/data/com.xxx/databases` as the database path, it should be just `/data/data/com.xxx/databases` without the `file://` .

Still waiting for the answers to the different between `DomStorage`, `Database`, `AppCache`.