# Access localStorage of a WebView from native code

Tags: javascript, android, caching, webview, offline

My application stores web pages for offline access using a WebView.

I need to access the cached images of those pages via native code.

I first tried (unsuccessfully) reading ApplicationCache.db, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20370804/372086), it's not a good idea, since the database format changes between Android versions.

I had an idea of using localStorage on my web page. Is it possible to access the stored information from native code?

Comment: ApplicationCache and local Storage are two different things. If you are using localstorage , this link could help you !- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615526/android-webview-localstorage

Comment: This answers clear the diffrence -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407220/in-androids-webview-whats-the-different-between-domstorage-database-ap?rq=1

Comment: I know that they are two different things.
I need to store something from within a webview and access it from native code.

The application cache is inaccessible from the native code, so I'm trying to use localStorage as an alternative (for example I can store the images as strings in the local storage and then access it via the JS bridge).

I was wondering if I could access the localStorage database directly from native code.

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 4.4, you could use the WebView.evaluateJavascript API to get a result back from a javascript snippet, i.e. you could interrogate localStorage and parse the result returned. Prior to 4.4, I think using a JS bridge will be your only reasonable option. I guess you'd hook up the bridge to a StorageEvent listener in your javascript (this approach would work in 4.4, too).